# Is Echoing Spell + Spell Perfection infinite castings?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Or perhaps worded otherwise, can one apply metamagic feats (via Spell Perfection) to a Echoed copy of a spell?

Imagine a caster with [Spell Perfection](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-perfection) (Lightning Bolt) and the [Echoing Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/echoing-spell-metamagic) feat. Could she continue to add Echoing Spell each time she casts it, never losing it from memory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No**

> No effect that allows you to reprepare or recast a spell can affect the echoed spell.

While *Echoing Spell* doesn't explicitly call itself out, I'd certainly consider it an effect that allows re-casting and as such can't be re-applied.

So while Spell Perfection may allow you to add a metamagic feat to the second cast, it can't be a second (or third, or fourth...) Echoing Spell because Echoing Spell forbids it.

Answer (score 4):

### You can't "re-echo" an echoing spell

The rules for Echoing Spell feat state:

> When you cast an echoing spell, it does not disappear entirely from memory, and you can cast it one additional time during that day. **No effect that allows you to reprepare or recast a spell can affect the echoed spell**.

<sup>(**Emphasis** mine)</sup>

So, this feat explicitly states you cannot gain more than one recasting of the spell.
Spell Perfection may allow you to add a single metamagic effect "for free" - but you cannot apply the Echoing Spell metamagic a second time on the same "echoed spell".

Bottomline - at most, you can double your casting potential if all your spells are echoed, but you can't gain a third casting using the same slot/casting-per-day...

Comment: Wow. That's some unusual language in that feat. It's like the author just gave up or something.

Comment: Yeah, but at least it's clear that he was aware that this feat might be abused, and that sentence is very difficult to misinterpret...

Comment: The typical response to that is *Then don't write the feat.* Seriously, if the author can't figure out a way to balance the feat with the existence [*pearls of power*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/pearl-of-power)--which have been around for nearly *40 years*--, maybe the problem *isn't* the player. ***But*** I appreciate the author's sentiment. I do think many feats could probably benefit from the reminder text *Don't be a jerk.*